# How to parse json array without root element in android?

Tags: php, android, json

I want to parse this json array in android?what is the best way to do it in android or what is the best way to create json array to relevant android json parsing.

MySql Table Data(sample)

```
key | name | lgtime
--------------------
1   | Cat 1| 899011
2   | Cat 2| 899011
3   | Cat 3| 899011
4   | Cat 4| 899011
```

This json array create from php

```
public static function getCategory($_lgtime) {
        $con = JsonDataManip::connect();
        $stmt = $con->prepare("select * from " . _TABLE_CATEGORY . " where lgtime > ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($_lgtime));
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $jsonArray['key'] = $row['key'];
            $jsonArray['name'] = $row['name'];
            $jsonArray['lgtime'] = $row['lgtime'];
            $json[] = $jsonArray;
        }
        return $json;
    }
```

**usage :(php)**

```
echo json_encode(JsonDataManip::getCategory('899011'));

[{
"key":"1",
"name":"Cat 1",
"lgtime":"899011"
},
{
"key":"2",
"name":"Cat2",
"lgtime":"899011"
},
{
"key":"3",
"name":"Cat 3",
"lgtime":"899011"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
try {
            JSONArray arrJsonArray = new JSONArray("AboveJsonString");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = arrJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("Key :" + object.getString("key"));
                System.out.println("name :" + object.getString("name"));
                System.out.println("lgtime :" + object.getString("lgtime"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way and let me know still have problem
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("jsonArrayString");

            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)toList(jsonArray);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private Object fromJson(Object json) throws JSONException {
        if (json == JSONObject.NULL) {
            return null;
        } else if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
            return jsonToMap((JSONObject) json);
        } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
            return toList((JSONArray) json);
        } else {
            return json;
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> jsonToMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
        Iterator keys = object.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            map.put(key, fromJson(object.get(key)).toString());
        }
        return map;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private List toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        int size = array.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add(fromJson(array.get(i)));
        }
        return list;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this string in String object

Like

```
String jsonString = "[
 {
   'key': '1',
   'name': 'Category 10',
   'lgtime': '20140129184514896'
 },
 {
   'key': '2',
   'name': 'Category 9',
   'lgtime': '20140129184514896'
 },
 {
   'key': '3',
   'name': 'Category 8',
   'lgtime': '20140129184514896'
 }
]"
```

**Create object of JSONArray Class**

Like : `JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonString)`

**Now create a loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr .length(); i++) {           
JSONObject obj = jsonArr.getJSONObjetc(i);                        
// Access you element bu this object like obj.getString("key");
}
```